# Linq to SQL Entity stored in a ViewState problem

Tags: linq-to-sql, viewstate

I'm trying to stored a Linq To SQL Entity within a ViewState.
However when I do so, it results in the following error:
Error serializing value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RequireApps.RequireLinqDataAccess.GroupMember]' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[RequireApps.RequireLinqDataAccess.GroupMember, RequireApps.RequireLinqDataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].'

Anyone have any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Thanks!
Rusty

Answer (score 1):

Anything you add to ViewState must be serializable, so you need to mark `RequireApps.RequireLinqDataAccess.GroupMember` as [`Serializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx):

```
namespace RequireApps
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GroupMember
    {

    }
}
```